# How do I hook up an LDAP server using Spring 3.0.5

Tags: spring, ldap

What is is the easiest, simplest/straight forward way of hooking up an LDAP server using spring 3.0.5?

**applicationContext-security.xml**

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
  xmlns:s="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/security http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.0.xsd">

   //? how do I set this up

</beans>
```

**web.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
  id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">

  .
  .
  .//etc

  <context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>
        /WEB-INF/applicationContext-security.xml
        /WEB-INF/spring.xml
    </param-value>
  </context-param>

  <filter>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
  </filter>

  <filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/secure/*</url-pattern>
  </filter-mapping>

   .
   .
   .//etc

</web-app>
```

**spring.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd">

  <bean id="configService" class="com.ConfigController"></bean>

</beans>
```

Comment: Are you asking how to use an LDAP server to perform authentication? Or authorization as well?

Comment: Thanks for the response MikeG. I guess essentially both. I read enough to understand how an ldap server works but never actually had to use one till now. How do I get my spring to hookup and authenticate/authorize against one?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you already decided to use Spring Security. There are built in classes there already for working with [LDAP Authentication](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.0.x/reference/ldap.html). Spring Security is using Spring LDAP's helper classes, so that's another option if you want something more customizable.

There are also ways to tie DB and LDAP access together with Spring Security. This would allow you to do auth with LDAP but have "side" data stored in a database.

Do you already have an existing LDAP setup; i.e. do you have a schema you are working with? If not, you could design your LDAP as needed to fit into the Spring model. But, just like with a database (which LDAP is, mostly), this can cause other issues.

Comment: There is a schema being used. I hold the xsd files. But I'm unsure on how to even use them with spring stuff. I will gladly take an easier route (if you know of any easy step-by-step tutorials)

Comment: I meant LDAP schema, which is like a database schema, not the XSD files. Do you already have users (and attributes) defined in an existing LDAP?

I am not having any luck finding a tutorial for Spring Security 3 and LDAP. Is section 18.4.5 in the documentation enought to get you started?